# What are the supported html tags in the htmlText parameter of ActionScript3 components?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Am working on a flash component that is supposed to display some dynamic text which might include HTML formatting. This text is displayed in a label component (AS3), and i would want it to render correctly, like create a line break when `<br>` is inserted, but it doesn't!

So am wondering what the supported HTML tags in the label component, and in general all other flash components?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a complete [list in the help docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText). If you want my advice, try to use the htmlText property as little as possible for complex layout issues. It's a bag of hurt as soon as you mix in images or want to try some more advanced (=by standards of 2001) CSS.

Cheers,
EP.

Comment: Thanks, actually access to the reference solve some other issues I had. Thanks for the link